# Receiving Google Play Store crash reports from devices that manually install the apk

Tags: android, package, apk, android-vitals

Customers require specific versions of my Android application and do not wish for their device to update the application to a newer version at any point. I would like to receive crash reports from all the various versions of my application.

My application is published in the Google Play Store and is regularly updated with newer versions. I also compile each version with a different package name and maintain a database of old APKs so that I may provide my customers with a legacy version that will not receive updates.

I wish to receive crash reports from all version. Is there a way to direct crash reports to the single listing I have in the Google Play Store? Would I have to create a separate Google Play Store listing for each version of my application with the unique package names? Is there a way to receive crash reports independent of the Google Play Store? I am also interested in viewing other statistics, but the crash reports are most important.

Is there another approach to providing legacy support for my customers that would make it easier to receive crash reports?

Google Play Store only shows vitals for installations with matching package names (which is expected). I would like to see vitals even if my package name is different. It appears that I can receive reports from installations that occur separately from the google play store as long as the package names are the same.

Comment: "Is there a way to receive crash reports independent of the Google Play Store?" -- there are [many options for this](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/21), such as [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend implementing **Firebase Analytics** into your app. **Firebase Analytics** is provided for free from **Google**. As long as every version of your app has a snippet with the same ID number that lets **Firebase** crawl, you will get reports from all of your apps at the single dashboard and it is much better than just **Google Play's** report.